# wordpress jQuery ajax loads unwanted duplicate posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I will try to explain the best I can. Basically I have a grid (masonry) of items and I want to append ajax loaded content (wordpress single.php post) inside each grid div (red).

I have a div class called **ajaxcontainer** inside each red div that I populate with content. When I click the a href trigger content gets appended as it should, this works once but when I click another item in the grid the old ajaxcontainer gets populated with new content from that href. Basically duplicating.

I want the old ajaxcontainer to keep the old content even though I click another item.

[image]
HTML

```
<article style="background:<?php echo $color ?>;" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" 
<?php post_class($classes); ?>>


<div class="hover">
<h2><?php echo $head ?></h2>
<p class="tags"><?php echo $tagsstring; ?></p>

<a href="//<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $url ?></a>
<a class="trick" rel="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">goto</a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail <?php echo $paddingstring?>" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $thumbnail[0] ?>);">

</div>


</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

What I have right now:

```
   $.ajaxSetup({
       cache: false,
       success: function (result, status, xhr) {
           // not showing the alert
           console.log('success');
           var $this = jQuery(this)
           $('.ajaxcontainer', $this).hide().fadeIn();
       },
       beforeSend: function () {
           console.log('beforesend');
           $(".ajaxcontainer").html("loading...");


       },
       complete: function (xhr, stat) {
           // hide dialog // works

       }
   });
   $(".trick").each(function () {
       $(this).on("click", function (e) {
           $(this).parents('.item').append("<div class='ajaxcontainer'>hello world</div>")

           var post_link = $(this).attr("href");
           $(".ajaxcontainer").load(post_link + ' #content');
           return false;
       });
   });
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: edited post - added html

Comment: where is the parent div with class "item"

Comment: try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/arunu/W5nyJ/3/

Comment: the class .item is in the article div, generated by wordpress. the fiddle was pretty close but now I don't know how to make it load the posts again

Comment: can u add ur page source html in js fiddle and try

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong, but from what I see, if you have duplicated content, next() could help.

Something like  $(this).parents('.item').next().append("hello world") in the function.